# Unit testing and too many mocks

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm starting to practice TDD in my project, as a background it also contains legacy code. We use Mockito as a mocking framework and follow a Spring MVC approach.

There are times when there's a `Service` class implemented with many different `DAO` objects as `@Autowired` properties. There are simple methods within these services, like for example `completeTransaction`.

`completeTransaction` will use many of the `DAO` objects to complete its responsibilities

- Update and save the transaction
- Advance a business process
- Closing other pending operations

However, in performing those operations, the method requires calls to different `DAO` to fetch and update the transaction, fetch a business process ID, fetch pending transactions (and save their updates). This means that unit testing this method makes me add many `@Mock` properties. And I need to set up the mock objects before the test will actually finish for me to test a certain condition.

This seems like a code smell, and to me it almost feels like the test is ensuring the implementation of the code instead of just its contract. Again, without mocking the dependencies, the test case will not run (due to NPE and others).

What is a strategy that I can follow to clean up code like this? (I can't really provide the actual source code on the question though). I'm thinking that one possibility would be to set up a facade class with methods like ("getPendingOperations" and "advanceBusinessProcess"). Then I can mock a single dependency. But then I figure that in all other classes that have situations like this I would need to do the same, and then I'm afraid to end up with a lot of "helper" classes just for the sake of cleaner tests.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I don't think there are any developers who haven't seen this, For Legacy code I try to write tests to test the whole flow so I will Mock the DAO and write the test at Controller level allowing the services and components to do what they are meant to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll want to do two things in general when you find yourself with too many mocks.  These are not necessary easy, but you may find them helpful.

1) Try and make your methods and classes smaller.  I think Clean Code says there are two rules, that classes should small.  And that classes should be smaller then that.  This makes some sense because as the units you are testing (methods and classes) get smaller, so will the dependencies.  You will of course end up with more tests, but they will have less setup in each test.

2) Look at the Law of Demeter (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).  There are a bunch of rules, but basically, you want to avoid long string of property/method calls.  `objA = objB.propertyA.SomeMethod().propertyC;`  If you need to mock out all of these objects just to get objA, the you will have a lot of setup.  But if you can replace this with `objA = objB.newProperty;` then you only need to mock objB and it's one property.

Neither of these are silver bullets, but hopefully you can use some of these ideas with your project.

Comment: I don't get it for 'If you need to mock out all of these objects just to get objA' part.
I think you can just make only one mock for multiple objects composing a reference chain.
Let's say we have an object SUT that we're testing, and SUT has OBJ1, and OBJ1 has OBJ2. Then, you can just mock OBJ1 because we can just define the result of all methods in OBJ1. OBJ1 becomes no longer dependent on OBJ2 if it is mocked.

Answer (score 0):

If the unit test is testing the `completeTransaction` method, then you must mock everything on which it depends.  Since you are using Mockito, you can use `verify` to confirm that the correct mocked methods are called and that they are called in the correct order.

If the unit test is testing something that calls the `completeTransaction` method, then just mock the `completeTransaction` method.

If this is your class hierarchy:

```
  class A -> class B -> class C
```

(where -> is "depends on")

In unit tests for class A, mock only class B.

In unit tests for class B, mock only class C.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the need to mock the dependencies, but what I'm trying to get at is that sometime it seems that the dependencies get out of hand. Where your test code ends up creating a large amount of `when(<something>).thenReturn()` just to set up what you're testing. When the setup code becomes large, it's hard to maintain tests.

Comment: When "dependencies get out of hand" then the root of the problem is not the unit test, but the class that is being unit tested.  If you have a situation where you have a large amount of setup, consider a non-test method to initialize the mock objects.  I recommend against using a non-test method to confirm the results of a unit test, but happily recommend them for setup.

Comment: I agree with @DwB; a few private methods for setup make it easier on the eye.